# How to dynamically allocate date?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table to store the name of product and it's renewal date along with the payment plan. For example there is a product named `"Domain Hosting"` with the Payment Plan `"Monthly"` and it's renewal date store in the table is `'15-11-2019'`, if I use the Select statement I want it to be shown for 12 months in 12 rows like shown below.

```
Product Name      Renewal Date   Payment Plan
Domain Hosting    2019-11-15     Monthly
Domain Hosting    2019-12-15     Monthly
Domain Hosting    2020-01-15     Monthly
Domain Hosting    2020-02-15     Monthly
Domain Hosting    2020-03-15     Monthly
Domain Hosting    2020-04-15     Monthly
Domain Hosting    2020-05-15     Monthly
Domain Hosting    2020-06-15     Monthly
Domain Hosting    2020-07-15     Monthly
Domain Hosting    2020-08-15     Monthly
Domain Hosting    2020-09-15     Monthly
Domain Hosting    2020-10-15     Monthly
```

It won't be store in the table so it has to be on run time.

Comment: join to a `tally` table. Something like `inner join tally t on t.num between 1 and 12`

Answer (score 3):

Here's your query, we achieve this using `recursive queries`.

```
  with cte as (
    select 0 as ctr
    union all
    select ctr + 1 from cte where ctr < 11
  ) select 'Domain Hosting' as [Product Name]
    , cast(dateadd(month, ctr, '2019-11-15') as date) as [Renewal Date]
    , 'Monthly' as [Payment Plan]
  from cte
```

**output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
;with AllDates AS
(
  SELECT CAST('2019-11-15' AS DATE) AS Dates
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DateAdd(month,1,Dates)
  FROM AllDates
  WHERE 
  Dates < DateAdd(month,11,CAST('2019-11-15' AS DATE))
)
SELECT 'Domain Hosting' as [Product Name], Dates, 'Monthly' as [Payment Plan] FROM AllDates
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=eb8ca6285794b5a9b5e04d65ae0e8f95)**

[image]